# Allow only one PC (one IP address) registration on a site

Tags: php, html

I have a registration site that requires the user to create their account by inputting a username and email address.

I site should only allow one email address to be registered from one PC (one IP address).

If another email account is registered from the same PC it will trigger a message saying "Your PC or PC's IP is already registered to the site" and refuse the account to be created.

Comment: This is probably not a good idea, as today many computers share a single public IP address. Additionally, many public IP addresses are reused between computers. The assumption 1 IP address = 1 computer is not true.

Comment: Also you can spoof IP address

Comment: Show me the code you tried and I will implement this to you. No one is going to give you a code for registration from scratch!

Answer (score 0):

```
function get_client_ip() {
    $ipaddress = '';
    if (getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP');
    else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR');
    else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED');
    else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR');
    else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED'))
       $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED');
    else if(getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
    else
        $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';
    return $ipaddress;
}
```

Use this function to find the IP address and save it to db. Before saving the registration data verify if the IP is already present in DB or not.

However, its always a bad idea as Single IP doesn't mean single PC. Their is single outgoing IP while their may be 1000+ systems using the same IP inside the organisation. Schools, Universities , Enterprises generally have few outgoing IP's while 1000's systems are connected internally.

Comment: These headers must not be used blindly -- they can be set by a client, and should not be trusted outside a reverse proxy configuration. Some of them I've never even seen used ("Forwarded"??).

Comment: @duskwuff FORWARDED header is set by proxy servers. Because if their is a proxy server in between client and server.. the server will receive proxy server address instead of client address. So, some proxy servers used to keep the original client IP in `FORWARDED ` header.

Comment: @duskwuff no user actually uses `FORWARDED ` headers. These are meant to be only for server and proxies. As headers can be set to any key value pair.. I have pointed out used to common proxy servers.

Comment: You don't _want_ to trust client IPs passed to you by random proxy servers. There's no way to tell if they're accurate -- or if they're even proxy servers.

Comment: @duskwuff IP can't be trusted, But as the OP asked the method, i have given him the solution. This discussion is not about trusting IP or not.. the question is about getting client IP. I think this is the most common solution used by php developers worldwide.